# Knockout.js - cross-iframe observable binding

Tags: javascript, iframe, knockout.js

I would like to use knockout.js in cross iframe binding. Existence of iframes is dictated by actual app structure I am working on.

**This is the scenario (simplified):**

1. Main window: Knockout.js included. `window.top.DATA` is a global container for data, ex. `var DATA = { username: ko.observable('John') };`
2. Module iframe window: Knockout.js also included. View wants do display data stored in `window.top.DATA` object, using code: `<div data-bind="text: window.top.DATA.username></div>`

**What is the result?**

DIV's innerHTML contains `ko.observable().toString()` contents instead of `John`.

**The cause**

Knockout.js is unable to recognize an observable created in parent frame while performing binding, because knockout checks if variable is observable with `ko.hasPrototype` by comparing references. Since prototypes are different between parent and child frame `ko` instances, it is impossible to bind values.

**Solutions**

The simplest solution would be writing something like: `window.ko = window.top.ko || setupKO()` on the top of script file. Unfortunately, in this case binding like `with: window.someLocalObj` is referencing to `window.top` instead of `window` - we are not able to access local variables and also local templates using `template` binding.

Another way to fix the problem is simply allow knockout to recognize observables as it should, what would allow observables to track dependency, bind values and just work well. Unfortunately I expect it might be difficult thing to achieve. What options do you see here?

Thank you for all your responses.

**Edit**

Knockout.js version: 3.2.0.

Comment: I've hit this myself in knockout.  What version are you using?  I think there's a bug in 3 that makes this not work, whilst 2 does.

Comment: what if you do window.top.DATA.username()

Comment: @Shiala evaluating observable manually makes value visible, but changing value of window.top.DATA.username does not populate changes in HTML. It seems that knockout does not subscribe observable because of problem with recognizing that this is observable.

Comment: What's the origin situation in your app? Are both parent and child running on the same TLD? If yes, you might get away with creating something like a `syncOnUpdate` extender that allows an iframe-local copy of an observable to be synced to the parent one. `var iframeObservable = ko.observable(); window.top.observable.extend({ syncOnUpdate: iframeObservable });`. If not, I would look into a solution that broadcasts changes to observables via [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage), with a listener on the other side that syncs the local copy.

Comment: @janfoeh Every frame works on the same domain. Your idea could be useful, but this solution will be very problematic over the time, when amount of observables will grow.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a single `ko` instance to handle main window and its frames elements at the same time. `iframe` elements are acessible through `window.frames[frame_index].document`:

```
  var DATA = { username: ko.observable('John') };

  ko.applyBindings(DATA);
  ko.applyBindings(DATA, window.frames[0].document.body);
```

**Working example:** [***`Plunker`***](http://plnkr.co/edit/JjEBG2fBlPQD24nR5Tui?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately applying bindings from window.top makes difficult to access any iframe variable directly from view template. It seems there is no easy way to solve this problem when views are separated between windows. Because of that the best solution will be to rebuild the knockout's part of app and make it able to work in the main window. As the library was constructed for. Fortunately it is possible.